# Simplifying a logical statement

Tags: logic

Let S stand for the statement “Steve is happy” and G for “George is happy.” What English sentences are represented by the following expressions?

S ∨ [G ∧ (¬S ∨ ¬G)]

On this question: [Simplifying ambiguous statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885946/simplifying-ambiguous-statements), Adriano answers with

S ∨ [G ∧ (¬S ∨ ¬G)]≡S ∨ [(G ∧ ¬S) ∨ (G ∧ ¬ G)]
                   ≡S ∨ (G ∧ ¬S) 
                   ≡(S ∨ G) ∧ (S ∨ ¬S) 
                   ≡S ∨ G
                   ≡"Steve is happy or George is happy (or both)."

It is concluded that Steve is happy or George is happy (or both), but can't we see from line 2 (S ∨ (G ∧ ¬S)) that it is impossible for both to be the case? Since if George is happy, Steve is not happy?

If someone could tell me why my guess is false, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You are wrong. If we assign TRUE to both $S$ and $G$ we get: $[TRUE \lor [ TRUE \land (FALSE \lor FALSE)] \equiv [TRUE \lor [ TRUE \land FALSE ] \equiv [TRUE \lor FALSE] \equiv TRUE$.

Answer (score 1):

The line $$S\lor (G\land \neg S)$$ means

> Steve is happy or George is happy and Steve is not

This means one of the two things is true. Either Steve is happy, or George is happy and Steve is not.

The sentence does **not** say that if George is happy, Steve is not happy, since, if both are happy, then sentence "Steve is happy or X" is true, no matter what $X$ is.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! So does ∨ *always* indicate that it is possible for both statements to be true?

Comment: @AlKanNot Yes, that's what the logical "or" does.